# Com+ components registration status by passing machine name using c#

Tags: c#, .net, com+, component-services, comadmin

How to get the list of com+ components registered in the machine by passing machine name using c#. I have tried using comadmincatalog.connect("machine name/ip address"). Getting exception like below

the component or application containing the component has been disabled

Please confirm how to resolve this issue

Comment: Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/0x80004027-remotely-access-com-plus-object

Comment: Thanks this helps. Whether any impact on changing windows firewall and regedit values